# Magnetic permeability dispersion

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Why is it that in Books they cover only the properties of the dispersion of the dielectric function but not The one of the magnetic permeability? I mean the function μ(ω)... It is like the dispersion of this function is less importante but I don't get why

Comment: What material are you looking at? Is $\mu (\omega)$ more or less constant for the range of frequencies you are considering?

Comment: Theres not a specific interval, it Just seems that this function does not need a treatment similar to epsilon whatever the frequency

Comment: of course, the subject is discussed extensively, for example in Bozorth: Ferromagnetism, page 800